# JMS MessageConsumer's messageListener makes push or pull?

Tags: java, jms

What really happens under the hood when i set a messageListener on my queue MessageConsumer object. Does the MessageConsumer object make some sort of polling ehind the scene or this is a real push made by the JMS server?

Java Message Service (O'Reilly Java Series) by David A. Chappell, Richard Monson-Haefel and Mark Richards, p10 CHAPTER1: Point-to-point

*The point-to-point messaging model has traditionally been a pullbased or polling-based model, where messages are requested from the queue instead of being pushed to the client automatically*

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS4.html#wp79175

*When message delivery begins, the JMS provider automatically calls the message listener's onMessage method whenever a message is delivered.*

Thanks,
Kod

Answer (score 1):

These two do not contradict each other. P2P is essentially pull-based, in that it is receiver's responsibility to read a message once it is sent by a producer. onMessage() method that you mentioned in your 2nd quote is a *notification* mechanism used to initiate the pull. These variations also referred to as sync vs async modes of receiving JMS messages, as for example in [this chapter in Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncfa.html).