# Custom polling vs JMS MessageListener

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, hornetq

Sorry, if it is a duplicate question.

I have a legacy web application which uses Queues (yes. normal Java Queue) and custom polling (every 500ms). A REST web service (/message) will be called, which will return the message if any otherwise empty string.

My need: If any message is available in Queue, in Real-Time, the client should get the message. So I can save 500ms.

Is there any advantage to moving to JMS from current approach? From this link [JMS MessageConsumer's messageListener makes push or pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108287/jms-messageconsumers-messagelistener-makes-push-or-pull) it seems, MessageListener (process is asynchronous) uses polling which is no different from current approach.

If it is vendor based, how HornetQ/ActiveMQ supports MessageListener?

EDIT:
The queue is used for integration of two systems. A web app & standlone java program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either receive or a MessageListener will be asynchronous and will be called as soon as you receive a message.

you could control the pre-fetch size of your client.

Now, if all you need is to avoid the delay of poling every 500 ms, using a Queue system may be an overkill? It's perfect fine to use java.util.Queue (or any other subclass).

If all you need is to block until an element of a java.util.Queue is available, and you don't need distributed messaging, persistence or anything like you could simply using BlockingDequeue and your thread would unblock as soon as you have a message..

Look at this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html

Comment: The queue is used for integration of two systems. I want to reduce the server load due to polling (approx. 10K polling per 500ms)

Answer (score 2):

The Async MessageListener is implemented using a push based model.  In ActiveMQ the broker sends a number of messages to the client based in it's set prefetch value so that messages are ready for consumption.   Whether or not this helps with your particular use case is a question you need to answer for yourself.

Comment: Any idea how it is implemented with HornetQ?

Comment: From HornetQ forum I found that it is also push model. Thanks Tim